# Unable to display TableViewer inside a scrolled composite

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, rcp

I'm trying to show 2 table viewers and buttons in between them. When trying to
achieve the `TableViewer` to show horizontal and vertical scroll bars, I'm unable to see the `TableViewer`, only `ScrolledComposite` can be seen. I even tried creating a composite inside the `ScrolledComposite` and used that composite for showing `TableViewer` but still cannot see the `TableViewer`. Can someone point me in the right direction.

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gridData.heightHint = 500;
    gridData.widthHint = 700;
    Composite parentComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
    parentComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);
    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_1 = new ScrolledComposite(parentComposite, SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite_1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gridData.heightHint = 200;
    gridData.widthHint = 400;
    scrolledComposite_1.setLayoutData(gridData);
    scrolledComposite_1.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    TableViewer tableViewer1 = new TableViewer(scrolledComposite_1, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    tableViewer1.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    tableViewer1.getTable().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    tableViewer1.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(200,400));
    createButtonComposite(parentComposite,SWT.NONE);
    ScrolledComposite scrolledComposite_2 = new ScrolledComposite(parentComposite, SWT.H_SCROLL|SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
    gridData = new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    gridData.heightHint = 200;
    gridData.widthHint = 400;
    scrolledComposite_2.setLayoutData(gridData);
    scrolledComposite_2.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);
    TableViewer tableViewer2= new TableViewer(scrolledComposite_2, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE);
    tableViewer2.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
    tableViewer2.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(200,400));
    getShell().setText("My Dialog"); 
    return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScrolledComposite` requires you to call `setContents` to tell it the child control and also requires varies other settings. This works:

```
scrolledComposite_1.setContent(tableViewer1.getTable());
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandVertical(true);
scrolledComposite_1.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComposite_1.setMinSize(tableViewer1.getTable().computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

(and the same for the 2nd)

However `TableViewer` can display scroll bars itself so you don't really need `ScrolledComposite` at all:

```
Composite parentComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
parentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));
parentComposite.setLayoutData(gridData);

TableViewer tableViewer1 = new TableViewer(parentComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
tableViewer1.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
tableViewer1.getTable().setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
tableViewer1.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(200,400));

createButtonComposite(parentComposite,SWT.NONE);

TableViewer tableViewer2= new TableViewer(parentComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
tableViewer2.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);
tableViewer2.getTable().setLayoutData(new GridData(200,400));
```

Comment: I'm able to achieve the layout what I want, but now I'm using ListViewer in SWT isnatead of TableViewer here, Is there any way that I can add click listener instead of DoubClickListener to it.

Comment: That should be a new question.